# Mssql fetch array show error in while loop

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php-mssql

I'm write a query for take some result in mssql server ,that working but now they some errors ,the error is

> Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): 3 is not a valid MS SQL-result resource
>   in

my connection query is working and there is no problem, my query like this

```
$qry="select cd_pcp,pcp_nm from tbl_m_pcp order by cd_pcp asc";
$result=mssql_query($qry);
while($row1=mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row1['cd_pcp'];
}
```

var_dump the $result show

> resource(3) of type (mssql result)

the query is execute in sql-server whyshow this type error any way to solve this issue please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible explanation is the return value from `mssql_query()`:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns a MS SQL result resource on success, TRUE if no rows were
> returned, or FALSE on error.

It's important to check the result from `mssql_query()`:

```
<?php
...
$qry = "select cd_pcp,pcp_nm from tbl_m_pcp order by cd_pcp asc";
$result = mssql_query($qry);
if ($result === true) {
    echo "No rows are selected";
} else if ($result === false) {
    echo "Error. ".mssql_get_last_message();
    exit;
} else {
    while ($row1 = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row1['cd_pcp'];
    }
}
...
?>
```

Notes:

MSSQL extension was removed in PHP 7.0. One good option is [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that var_dump will always return "mssql result" independent if the return is successful or not. To do the debugging test if the value is returning FALSE

```
$result = mssql_query($qry,$conn);
if(!$result)  {
   die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

Comment: this will not enter in if condition